# Как в web api вернуть формат данных, который я запрашиваю

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Например я запрашиваю `"text/xml"` и мне приходит ответ в Xml формате? Нашел, что есть OutputFormatters, но не очень понял как с ним работать. Еще, видимо, с этим как-то связан атрибут `[Produces]`, однако он тоже вызывает вопросы

Comment: Может эта заметка прояснит ситуацию https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/formatting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В старом ASP.NET Web API (не Core) уже подключены два форматтера, для XML и для JSON.

В Web API Core по умолчанию есть только JSON, XML-форматтер необходимо подключать дополнительно. Для этого в файл `project.json` добавьте пакет `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml` (в раздел `dependencies`):

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.0.1-*"
```

Затем в startup-классе в методе `ConfigureServices` вызовите `AddXmlSerializerFormatters`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

Теперь требуемый формат данных можно указать в заголовке `Accept` запроса к контроллеру (если заголовок не указан, возвращается JSON):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/api/test');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/xml');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        console.log(request.responseXML);
    }
};
request.send();
```

Или, если использовать jQuery, нужно установить параметр `dataType` в `'xml'`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/test',
    dataType: 'xml'
}).then(function (data) {        
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: может быть Вы еще проясните когда используется `InputFormatters`?

Comment: @Qutrix написал в ответе к вашему второму вопросу по FromBody